# Mongoose - Unable to create more than 4 fields using `findOrCreate`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am using Node.js, MongoDB with Mongoose and am using passport.js for authentication.

Here is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  profilePic: String,
  fName: String,
  lName: String
});
```

And my google strategy:

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/dashboard",
      profileFields: ["id", "displayName", "photos", "email"]
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(profile);
      console.log(profile.photos[0].value);
      User.findOrCreate(
        { googleId: profile.id },
        { profilePic: profile.photos[0].value },
        { email: profile.emails[0].value },

        function(err, user) {
          return cb(err, user);
        }
      );
    }
  )
);
```

When I `console.log` my result I see my profile, along with profile photo url and profile email but I am unable to see my email id. Only 4 fields are getting created :

- `_id`
- `googleId`
- `profilePic`
- `_v`

Can someone tell me how to get the email field to save too?

Comment: I can't seem to find the `Model.findOrCreate` method in the mongoose documentation, what version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: I am using a separate mongoose findOrCreate plugin which adds  findOrCreate method to models. This is useful for libraries like Passport which require it. you can find additional details here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-findorcreate

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are having the issue:**
You are not using the `findOrCreate` method well. `findOrCreate` can take up to four arguments.
`findOrCreate(conditions, doc, options, callback)`:

- `conditions`: This is used to specify the selection-filter
  to find the document.
- `doc`[optional]: If a document that matches the selection-filter(`conditions`) is not found, this `doc` is merged with what is you have in `conditions` and then inserted into the DB.
- `options`[optional]: From the plugin codebase, I figured you can use
  `options.upsert`(if set to `true`) to update the document if it
  already exist.
- `callback`: The function executed after the operation is done.

What you are doing wrong is passign `{ email: profile.emails[0].value }` as the third argument where `options` is expected, you are supposed to include it in the `doc` i.e the second argument.

**The Fix**
Try this:

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/dashboard",
      profileFields: ["id", "displayName", "photos", "email"]
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(profile);
      console.log(profile.photos[0].value);
      User.findOrCreate(
        { googleId: profile.id },
        // Notice that this function parameter below 
        // includes both the profilePic and email
        { profilePic: profile.photos[0].value, email: profile.emails[0].value },
        function(err, user) {
          return cb(err, user);
        }
      );
    }
  )
);
```