# Using passport-google-oauth20, trying to create item mongo for picture URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm trying to create an item in a mongoDB table that contains the 'picture' URL from the profile of a google user logging in to my app using **passport-google-oauth20**.

The following is my schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  picture: String,
  googleId: String,
});
```

The following is the google strategy:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    console.log(profile._json.picture);
    const customerEmail = profile._json.email;
    User.findOrCreate(
      { googleId: profile.id },
      { name: profile.displayName },
      { picture: profile._json.picture },
      function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

in my mongo table it will create items for the 'googleId' and 'name', but will not create an item for 'picture'. and no error messages for this.

however interestingly i can `console.log(profile._json.picture);` and it does actually log the string (which is a URL - unsure if the fact its a URL has anything to do with this??)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? My assumption is that its an issue at the MongoDB side, as the URL string is being returned in the console.log.

Comment: Hi there! I guess you are using the mongoose [findOrCreate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-findorcreate) plugin, the root cause of this problem is from how you are using the `User.findOrCreate()` method, you are passing the arguments in wrongly. I answered a question just like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393424/mongoose-unable-to-create-more-than-4-fields-using-findorcreate/60438662#60438662), check it out to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Tunmee Yes that has worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: You can upvote that answer so that it can be more visible to others facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Tunmee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7685866/tunmee) and his answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393424/mongoose-unable-to-create-more-than-4-fields-using-findorcreate/60438662#60438662).
I was not using the findOrCreate method correctly. I have change my function as follows:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    var profilePicture = profile._json.picture;
    console.log(profilePicture + "inside function");
    const customerEmail = profile._json.email;
    User.findOrCreate(
      { googleId: profile.id, name: profile.displayName, picture: profile._json.picture  },
      function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
```

Previously the other keys and values that I wanted in my MongoDB documents were passed as the different arguments, rather than just the conditions argument.